# To prove $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^{x\cos x}}{x-\sin x}=3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I came across this question to prove the given limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^{x\cos x}}{x-\sin x}=3$$
First I tried using LHospital's rule directly.
Then I tried using expansion of $e^x$ and then using LHospital's rule but I am getting stuck.

Comment: Can you post your attempts, showing where you got stuck?

Comment: L'Hopital's Rule might be easier if you factor $e^x$ out of the numerator.  After all this does not contribute to the indefinite form.

Comment: @hardmath How do you factor $e^x$ out of $e^{x\cos x}$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{e^x-e^{x\cos x}}{x-\sin x}=$$\displaystyle\frac{e^x-e^{x\cos x}}{x-x\cos x}$$\displaystyle\frac{ x-x\cos x }{x-\sin x}\approx \frac{x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}\to \frac{1/2!}{1/3!}=3$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor's series and easily get the answer, but these techniques are never applied directly (unless the problem is too simple).

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}-e^{x\cos x}} {x-\sin x} \notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{x\cos x} \cdot \frac{e^{x(1-\cos x)} - 1}{x(1-\cos x)}\cdot \frac{1-\cos x} {x^{2}}\cdot\frac{x^{3}}{x-\sin x} \notag\\
&=1\cdot 1\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot 6=3\notag
\end{align}
All the limits are well known and you can evaluate limit of $(x-\sin x) /x^{3}$ either using L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series to get $1/6$. Therefore its reciprocal tends to $6$.

Comment: Nicely constructed.  (+1)

Comment: Thanks @MarkViola. Glad to receive your positive feedback. I try to split the expression in terms of sub-expressions so that certain standard limits can be utilized.

Comment: You're more than welcome.  And your technique renders application of LHR or Taylor's Theorem easy.

Answer (score 4):

Use $\cos(x) = 1 - \frac12 x^2 + \cal{O}(x^4)$ and $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \cal{O}(x^5)$. Then

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-e^{x\cos x}}{x-\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0}e^x\frac{1-e^{-x^3/2 + \cal{O}(x^5)}}{x-\sin x}= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{{x^3/2  + \cal{O}(x^5)}}{x^3/6 + \cal{O}(x^5)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{{1/2  + \cal{O}(x^2)}}{1/6 + \cal{O}(x^2)}= 3
$$

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using Taylor expansion:
First we calculate some ugly derivatives:
$$(e^{x\cos(x)})' = (\cos(x) - x\sin(x))e^{x\cos(x)},$$

$$(e^{x\cos(x)})'' = [(-2\sin(x) - x\cos(x))+(\cos(x)-x\sin(x))^2] e^{x\cos(x)}$$
and

$$(e^{x\cos(x)})''' = [(-3\cos(x) + x\sin(x))+(\cos(x)-x\sin(x))^3+2(\cos(x)-x\sin(x))(-2\sin(x)-x\cos(x)) ]e^{x\cos(x)}.$$

From that we have that the first, second and third derivatives of $e^{x\cos(x)}$ at $x=0$ are $1$ ,$1$ and $-2$. Therefore we have

$$e^{x\cos(x)} = 1+x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2-\frac{2}{3!}x^3+o(x^3).$$

Using the Taylor's expansion of $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$ we get:

$$e^x - e^{x\cos(x)} = -\frac{-3}{3!}x^3+o(x^3)$$
and
$$x-\sin(x) = -\frac{1}{3!}x^3+o(x^3).$$

Therefore we obtain
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x - e^{x\cos(x)}}{x-\sin(x) } = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{-3}{3!}x^3+o(x^3)}{-\frac{1}{3!}x^3+o(x^3)} = 3.$$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital worked. You need to do it three times.

$f(x) = e^{x} - e^{xcosx} ,   g(x) = x - sinx$

$f^{1}(x) = e^{x} - (cosx-xsinx)e^{xcosx},  g^{1}(x) = (1-cosx)$.

$f^{2}(x) = e^{x} - e^{xcosx}{(cosx-xsinx)^{2} -2sinx + xcosx}$,  $g^{2}$(x) = sinx.

$f^{3}$(x) = $e^{x} - (-2cosx - (cosx-xsinx))e^{xcosx} +  e^{xcosx}(cosx-xsinx)(-2sinx-xcosx) +(cosx-xisinx)^{3}e^{xcosx} + 2(-sinx-cosx-xsinx))e^{xcosx}$ 
 $g^{3}$(x) = cosx